# Tracking back button clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, back, html5-history

As part of our new product metrics, we are required to measure the number of back button clicks on the page.

Since the site is not AJAX and we make no use in "pushState", "popState" isn't firing when clicking back in the browser.

The only purpose of catching the back button event is registering an analytics event.

After Googling it for a couple of hours, and trying out several different solutions, I came up empty - oddly enough, javascript just does not seem equipped for such a task.

Having that said, this is not a valid response :) How would you handle such a requirement?

**Please note - bounty-awarded answer did not resolve my issue, but I have granted the bounty due to effort. It was the best answer undet the circumstances**

Comment: I think you are going to have to implement the [History API](https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API) and use the gooogle analytics  `track` function as callbacks

Comment: How about keeping a stack of urls in `localStorage` then comparing `location`, `referrer` and the last visited url in the stack to infer the user came back from another page within the website?

Comment: I think it's much simpler to just use the history api, as you say; you could confuse the back button with a voluntary click on a link ( again )

Comment: @ToniMichelCaubet yeah, it depends on whether the goal is to measure users going back from a page (no matter how) or to compare usage of the back button vs. other means of navigation. (i.e. patterns of navigation vs. UI interaction).

Comment: Thank you for your responses!
So, here's the deal - we're trying to measure navigation "unfriendliness", which means a couple of metrics, back button (not going back but the actual browser back) is one of them.
As far as the History API goes, I've been trying to implement it (using Modernizer, history.js and even plain HTML5) - but 'popstate' and 'statechange' isn't firing unless I use 'pushstate' - which means I will need to convert the whole site navigation to AJAX... Am I missing something?

Comment: I wonder how you can difference between the browser back button and other clicks when it's not ajax? Anyway you can "mix" your skills/techniques/applications?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm asking - how could I make the difference. And I can "mix my skills", just didn't find the right blend yet :)

Comment: @NoyGabay:IMO it's impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can catch the `window.onbeforeunload()` and use cookies to store the number of back button clicks on every backbutton fire, you can update the cookie. Try that.

---

Use popstate and cookies you can achieve
I used a plugin called [cookie](http://plugins.jquery.com/cookie/)

and also import them to your page.

Here is the import.

```
<script src="/jqueries/jquery.cookie.js"></script>
```

This is the code I used.

```
$(window).on('popstate', function () {
    var val = 1;
    if (typeof $.cookie('example') === 'undefined') {
        //no cookie
    } else {
        //have cookie
        val = parseInt($.cookie("example")) + 1;
        $.removeCookie("example");
    }
    $.cookie("example", val, { expires: 7 });
    //alert($.cookie("example"));
});
```

Its juzz a rough code You can make it as what you want It will create `pushstate`

Add this to the script..

There are just DEMO contents in HTML

```
<input type="text" id="t1" />
<input type="text" id="t2" />
<input type="text" id="t3" />
<input type="text" id="t4" />
<input type="text" id="t5" />
```

These are the HTML5 pushstate scripts without AJAXify. Try these...

```
    $('#t1').click(function () {
        if (window.history.replaceState) {
            window.history.pushState('', 'Title', '/YourPagename/123/1234');
        }
    });
    $('#t2').click(function () {
        if (window.history.replaceState) {
            window.history.pushState('', 'Title', '/YourPagename/123/12345');
        }
    });
    $('#t3').click(function () {
        if (window.history.replaceState) {
            window.history.pushState('', 'Title', '/YourPagename/123/123456');
        }
    });
```

And soon. Declare like these for others

By this it is possible.

This part is to get the url values passed, here t1, t2 will get the values associated with url

```
var ourl = "", t1 = "", t2 = "";
if (window.history.replaceState) {
    ourl = document.URL.toString();
    var url = document.URL.toString().replace('http://', '');
    var cnt = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < url.length; i++) {
        if (url[i] == '/') {
            cnt++;
        }
        else if (cnt == 2) {
            t1 += url[i];
        }
        else if (cnt == 3) {
            t2 += url[i];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, `window.onbeforeunload()` fires whenever I leave the page, not just on back button clicks.

Comment: well then use `popstate` and `cookies` that will help you. HTML% has that functionality man try that. It will surely help you.

Comment: OK, so as far as I know and have experimented, `'popstate'` only fires when preceded with pushstate - your handler will never fire..

Comment: have a `pushstate` and fire, without `pushstate` the back button is not enabled. What is your point?

Comment: Well, to have a pushstate I need to AJAXify my navigation, which I specifically stated as an overkill for an analytics event. And we're back at square one.

Comment: No need to AJAXify navigation I update the code which is having `pushstate` without AJAXify and also supports `popstate`. Wait for a minute.

Comment: @NoyGabay I did it, take a look at the edited code. I made it simple. You can make it as what you want.

Comment: I apologize for not being clear enough in my comment - I am aware of the solution which will require me to 'pushstate' in all of my navigation elements (which is a lot). I'm looking for a less intrusive way. Having that said, way to answer! Got my vote up if only for the effort.

Comment: P.S. - if I were to use pushstate, I'd probably handle the popstate in no more than 3 lines...

Comment: @NoyGabay I understand. But please have this, you can enable popstate without pushstate, so no backbutton without popstate, so without backbutton how could you record? This is the biggest question in my mind.

Comment: Since the back button outdated the push\popstate, I'm gonna go ahead and assume this logical rule has some exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure of any shortcut process but you can try following logic if nothing else works.

If you can't measure browser back button click directly, you can measure total back and go back click count in your website. You can subtract that and get your value.

Use this code.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
        if ($(this).attr('href') != 'javascript:void(0)') { // condition to check if its redirect href 
            e.preventDefault();
            localStorage.setItem('website_called', true);
            location.href = $(this).attr('href');
        }
    });

    window.onload(function() {
        if ((document.referrer).indexOf('yoursite.com') != -1 && localStorage.setItem('website_called') == false) {
            var backButtonUsed = localStorage.setItem('backButtonUsed');
            backButtonUsed = backButtonUsed + 1;
            localStorage.setItem('backButtonUsed', backButtonUsed);
        }
        localStorage.setItem('website_called', false);
    });
```

Comment: I have added code to my answer it might help. Check syntax and modify as per your requirement

Comment: That I can also infer from server access logs - assemble a flow and determine if the user went backwards - but that's not what I'm looking for. I would like to know when the user clicked on the back button rather then using the site's built in navigation.

Comment: I am not sure what you want but if you want the count of times back button of browser was clicked you can check that in localStorage->backButtonUsed as it is incremented only when back button of browser will be clicked as that time website_called flag will be false.

Comment: Alternatively if you want track on the page from where back button was clicked you can write the window.load code in window.unload event and write your code at the place where localstorage value is incremented